# How can i get records of id those are connected in multiple row value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, recursive-query

Following is my table

```
Id      User_id     type               content       item_id    secondary_item_id
   879       1         activity_comment   Amazing       833        833
   907       168       activity_comment   Great         833        879    
   908       1         activity_comment   Welcome       833        907
```

I want to output a comment reply structure, which can be described by an example. On the table above you can see user_id `1` post comment on **833** `( this is a post id )` a post, then `user 168` repliy to him as "Great" then after again `user 1` replay to user 168.

So it could be like...

```
**MY POST** ( This is a post )

---- First comment( Amazing)
------- replay comment  (Great)
------------ sub replay (Welcome )
```

I have written the following query but I could not get the output that I expect.

SQL Query:

```
<?php 
  $listReplay =$wpdb->get_results("(SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE id = ".$value['secondary_item_id']."  AND type ='activity_comment') UNION DISTINCT 
                            (SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE secondary_item_id = ".$value['secondary_item_id']." AND type ='activity_comment')");
?>
```

Comment: You have `item_id` and `secondary_item_id`. I would suggest updating that to `parent_id` or the main thread that is under discussion and a `replied_to_id` which would be the comment being replied to. Lastly, add a `timestamp` it makes sorting a heck of a lot better. As for the SQL to get that structure I would push that to code it a lot easier just get the data.

Comment: For hierarchical data much better to use nested set model. See https://phpro.org/tutorials/Display-Render-Nested-Set-MPPT-As-HTML-List.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, a typical approach is to use a recursive query to traverse the hierarchical data structure. This produces the desired result with a single query, so this is much more efficient that iterating in php.

```
with recursive cte as (
    select t.*, 1 lvl
    from mytable t
    where 
        type ='activity_comment' 
        and item_id = 833 
        and secondary_item_id = item_id
    union all
    select t.*, c.lvl + 1
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.id = t.secondary_item_id
    where t.type = 'activity_comment'
)
select * from cte order by lvl
```

The anchor of the recursive query selects the "first" comment of the post, which is we identify with condition `secondary_item_id = item_id`. Then, the recursive part just follows the relationships until they exhaust.

This gives you a flat structure that lists all comment's posts, with an addition column named `lvl` that indicates the depth of each element. You can use that information to handle the display in your application.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ef8aefd0a7b00361f111c4d43576f05)**:

```
 Id | User_id | type             | content | item_id | secondary_item_id | lvl
--: | ------: | :--------------- | :------ | ------: | ----------------: | --:
879 |       1 | activity_comment | Amazing |     833 |               833 |   1
907 |     168 | activity_comment | Great   |     833 |               879 |   2
908 |       1 | activity_comment | Welcome |     833 |               907 |   3
```

Comment: Not getting result ,it's displayed all the comments of item_id 833 not getting result that i have mentioned in my question, result must be in hierarchy comment structure.

Comment: @SamirSheikh: SQL queries return flat structures by design (rows cannot be "nested"). This query gives you the comments in the proper sequence (from the root to the children), with a column that indicates the depth of each node. This is as good as you can get with a SQL query. Starting from these results, it is easy to loop with php and use the `lvl` column to display the rows as a hierarchy in your application. And, again, remember that using a single query is much more efficient that iterating in php and running multiple queries.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: I see your point. There are solutions for this - depending on what OP wants. For example, we can keep track of the path to each comment, and use if for sorting. But OP's sample data does not show this use case, so I did not implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get your output in SQL.

```
WITH comment_activity(Id, User_id, type, content, post_id, secondary_item_id)
AS
(Select   879 ,     1     ,  'activity_comment' ,  'Amazing' ,      833     ,  833 UNION
Select   907 ,     168   ,  'activity_comment' ,  'Great'   ,      833     ,  879  UNION 
Select   908 ,     1     ,  'activity_comment' ,  'Welcome' ,      833     ,  907  
)

Select post_id as post,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY ID) as RN, 
content as comment,
User_id,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY ID) = 1
     THEN 'First_Comment (' + content + ')'
     ELSE 'Reply_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY ID) - 1) + '( ' + content + ')'
     END as Thread

from comment_activity
WHERE type = 'activity_comment'
AND post_id = 833
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually Lajos Arpad's solution could work with some changes in the db.
You add another column parent_item_id. Which is basically the first comment of that chain of comments. In your example it would be 879 for all the 3 rows.

Now this could work

```
select * from <table name> 
where item_id = <item_id> 
group by parent_item_id 
order by secondary_item_id asc
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's first understand how we can load the raw data:

```
select Id, content, item_id, secondary_item_id
from table_one
where item_id = 833
order by item_id, secondary_item_id;
```

The query above loads the comments on post 833 and orders them by the post id and the parent comment id. So far, so good. Now, assuming that you have the raw data stored in `$rawResults`, you can do the following:

```
$map = [];
$parsedResults = [];
foreach ($rawResults as $rawResult) {
    if ($rawResult["secondary_item_id"] === $rawResult["item_id"]) {
        $parsedResults[$rawResult["Id"]] = [
            "content" => $rawResult["content"],
            "children" => []
        ];
        $map[$rawResult["Id"]] = $parsedResults[$rawResults["Id"]];
    } else {
        $map[$rawResult["secondary_item_id"]]["children"][$rawResult["Id"]]= [
            "content" => $rawResult["content"],
            "children" => []
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, you have a hierarchy of elements, the main levels are main comments, to which you can find the answers in the children item. You can now traverse your hierarchical array like

```
function getComments($parsedResults, $prefix = "--- ") {
    $output = "";
    foreach ($parsedResults as $parsedResult) {
        $output .= $prefix.$parsedResult["content"]."\n";
        if (count($parsedResult["children"])) $output .= getComments($parsedResult["children"], "---".$prefix);
    }
    return $output;
}
```